# Suggest an algorithm/method for finding a proper value

Tags: algorithm

I have a bunch of values, for example: [1,2,14,51,100,103,107,110,300,505,1034]. 
And I have a pattern values, for example [1,10,20,100,500,1000].
I need to get the best 'suitable' value FROM pattern. In my example it is 100. How can I detect this value?

Example from life. The app has a bunch of distances between user position and some objects. The app also has a preset filter by distance: [1 meter, 10 meters, 20 meters, 100 meters]. I heed to set the filter by default not just to the first value (1 meter in my example), but to the value which match the bunch of distances the best way(100 meter in my example). I need to detect one value.

Thank you for help and any ideas.

Comment: How about assigning each of your values to the closest pattern value, then returning the pattern value with the most values assigned to it?

Answer (score 0):

I would say create a function like this (this is not real code) :

```
            var ratio1 = 0.66
            var ratio2 = 1.5
            function Score(currentPatternValue, arrayOfValues)
            {
            count = 0
            for each value in arrayOfValues <br>
              if value > ratio1 * currentPatternValue AND value < ratio2 * currentPatternValue<br>
                count++<br>

            return count
            }
```

then you run this for each value in your pattern values and pick the one with the highest score returned from that function